# Example to write optimised code by seeing compiler code of built-in classes

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction

This may not be a actual question, but I just asked it for the sake of gaining some valuable added knowledge. I have come across this many times(as in reading many articles and blogs) that once a person becomes an expert in a particular programming language, they have the tendency to optimize their code in whatever application they built by seeing how the minutest details are implemented by seeing the compiler code of each built in class they use for developing the application. But I have seen no example of such a situation. Can anyone please suggest any or give a snippet. I am quite good at Java so if any such optimization example exists in Java could anyone please write a code snippet.
If not I don't mind for any prog. language as the question encompasses almost the presently used ones.

Comment: Are you talking about optimization decisions taken based on knowledge of particularities of a language and/or its implementations (compilers, interpreters etc) ?

Comment: yes precisely based on that only

Comment: Hmm, I never have disassembled Java code, not because I think it cannot be optimized, but because compilers change (and improve!), while programs remain, so in my opinion, the best thing to do is to retain code readability while still optimizing things like object allocation (which may or may not add cost with Java), trading memory for CPU time using caching of data frequently used. Would you like me to give you an elaboration on all that with an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> once a person becomes an expert in a particular programming language, they have the tendency to optimize their code in whatever application they built by seeing how the minutest details are implemented by seeing the compiler code of each built in class they use for developing the application

Actually I would say the opposite, instead you are more likely to see

- beginners: just need to get anything which works.
- intermediate: try to optimise everything just because you can.
- expert: ease of understanding and maintenance is the most important.  Simple, clean code often performs best and when you can determine code needs to be optimised, only then do so. e.g. because you measured it with a profiler.

> Can anyone please suggest any or give a snippet

I suggest you read the code in the `java.lang.*`, `java.util.*` and `java.util.concurent.*`  These are widely used and expertly optimised for Java. If you are assuming that complicated or obtuse code is more "expert" you are likely to be disappointed. ;)

Comment: Paradoxically, at least with Java because of its design, many beginners can potentially write faster code, because they face fewer "gates" for making mistakes, just instead going for the approach they think makes sense. Of course, code clarity (or even worse, code reuse) suffer greatly, and are not even thought of until much later. With a language like C++, I often see the opposite - beginners copy stuff all over the place up to 3-4 times, return copies of large objects etc, while professionals go for indirection or at least copy-on-write.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I do admit what you have just said is true, but have you come across any such optimization that I just posted about other than the normal ones like dead code elimation, strength reduction and various loop optimizations, etc. And I feel knowing how compiler implements all the classes is a tough task is it ever done in real world with software applications.

Comment: @jerisalan It is worth nothing that the `javac` compiler does almost no optimisations, so attempting to optimise your code for what the compiler does is unlikely to be helpful.  Trying to second guess what the JVM will optimise is not a simple task, as most simple, easy to apply patterns are performed by the JVM already.

Comment: You might find these libraries interesting. They are all pretty advanced and might not make much sense even if you have ten years Java experience. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/high-performance-libraries-in-java.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey quite an interesting collection... No doubt I will go nuts understanding the intricacies involved in each for years...but thanks for helping me know and learn something knew today :D :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise anyone to try and outguess the optimizer built into the JVM itself.  It uses runtime statistics, based on the way your code is executing, to optimize your code on the fly.

I would advise that you write the cleanest, simplest code you can and let the JVM optimize at runtime.  If you have issues, profile the code to find them.