# Eliminating or avoiding adding duplicates in a ArrayList with custom Object

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have a custom object in this structure

```
static class Node {
    int col;
    int row;
    int g;
    int h;
    int f;

    public Node(int col, int row, int g, int h) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        this.g = g;
        this.h = h;
        this.f = g+h;
    }
}
```

The `col` and `row` variables are unique, and may only occur once in `ArrayList<Node> myList`.

Is there a way optimal way to avoid adding or checking for possible duplicate without having to make a nasty for-loop?

I am aware that `Set` interface possibly could be a solution for this as duplicates cannot occur, but i have alot of code right now, which i do not want to refactor unless it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are your options. All of these solutions require proper implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`. Since you want `row` and `col` to be unique:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != Node.class) {
        return false;
    }
    Node other = (Node) obj;
    if (other.col != this.col) {
        return false;
    }
    if (other.row != this.row) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result = 7;
    result += row * 31;
    result += col * 31;
    return result;
}
```

#### Iterate over the `List`

You don't have to do the iteration yourself, but that is exactly what calling `List.contains` will do. This one is pretty easy:

```
if (!myList.contains(node)) {
    myList.add(node);
}
```

This will iterate for you, so you don't have to write the loop.

#### `List` to `Set` to `List`

Here you have two sub-options. If you want to preserve the order of your input list, then you can use `LinkedHashSet`. If you don't care, you can just use `HashSet`. What I mean is if I have a `List` with elements A, B, C, converting it to a `HashSet` and back may produce a different list, like B, C, A. `LinkedHashSet` keeps the elements in insertion order, avoiding this problem. In any case, you'll just do this:

```
Set<Node> nodeSet = new [Linked]HashSet<Node>(myList);
nodeSet.add(node);
myList = new ArrayList<Node>(nodeSet);
```

Remember that this is essentially doing iteration as well, but it's using a hash-code shortcut instead of checking every element's equality, which may be a big deal with enough nodes. If your node list is small (less than 1000 elements) then I doubt this will make much of a difference, and you may as well use the first one.

#### Converting everything to `Set`

You mentioned that this would require a lot of refactoring in your code, but this isn't a bad thing, especially if you plan on working on this code a lot in the future. My rule of thumb is if the refactoring will make the code easier to maintain, adding a little extra development time is *never* a bad thing. Writing maintainable, readable, and understandable code [is what the experts do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015244/example-to-write-optimised-code-by-seeing-compiler-code-of-built-in-classes/13015420#13015420) (the question here isn't relevant, but this particular answer is). Since `Set` implies unique elements and `List` does not, then it makes sense to make the change. The compiler will pretty much tell you all the places you have to change with its errors, and it might take less time than you think.

Comment: So in other words. To keep it more clean i should refactor to `Set` and override the `equals()` method?

Comment: Im very tempted to traverse the entire list instead even though it will become `O(N)`.

Comment: That's a viable option too. If your list is fairly small (like I said in my answer, < 1000 elements) then doing all this stuff won't have much of a speed impact anyway. You can always write it to use `contains` and see if it's really that slow. If it starts getting too slow, then convert everything to `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a equals method in Node if possible :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Node n){
if(this.getRow().equals(n.getRow()) && this.getCol().equals(n.getCol())
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

And then use `list-to-set-to-list` trick.

Try this method:

```
List<Node> removeDuplicateNodes(List<Node> inputList){
return (inputList ==null or inputList.size()==0)? Collections.EMPTY_LIST: new ArrayList<Node>(new HashSet<Node>(inputList));
}
```

**Update :**

If you wan't to maintain input order, use `LinkedHashSet`

```
List<Node> removeDuplicateNodes(List<Node> inputList){
return (inputList ==null or inputList.size()==0)? Collections.EMPTY_LIST: new ArrayList<Node>(new LinkedHashSet<Node>(inputList));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all the elements to a new `Set`, then put all the elements from the `Set` to a new `List`. That will make it.

Comment: Don't forget to override equal() and hashCode() methods to check for the specific condition of equality that you want implemented

Answer (score 0):

I always find weird to see cases where people want to use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (for the `get(int)` method, I guess) when they require unicity, which is only achieved through `Set`.

Anyway, by manipulating a little the equals/hashcode (making equals return `true` when `row` and `col` are the same) method and adding calls to [`List#contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), you could have your goal reached without sacrifying your `List`

**EDIT**

Notice you could also create a Comparator and rely upon [`Collections#sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to have your list sorted and items with the same value melted into only one value.

Comment: I already have a sort algorithm, but i am sorting a entirely different criteria. So perhaps i might be better off using a Set instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd use `Set`, but if you'd like to avoid reimplementing your data structures from `ArrayList<Node>` to `Set`, you can implement `Set` as a gatekeeper:

- Each time an element is about to be inserted into your ArrayList, check if the row-col pair is already in the Set.
- If not, register the row-col pair into the Set
- If the pair already exists in the set, do not insert it
- Each time an element is about to be removed from your ArrayList, remove it from the Set.

And thus it's a "gatekeeper".

All of the Set operations are `O(1)` since they are hashed; minimal refactoring and no nasty loops as desired.

Comment: If i implement Set, how can i filter duplicates based on `row` and `col` and not the entire element?

Comment: Hmm, it appears that Pair<> is only in C++, and not Java. You can filter duplicates by overriding `Node`'s `.equals()`: where you check if both the rows and columns are equal, then the Nodes themselves are equal.

Comment: But this is not possible with an `ArrayList` in same fashion by overriding the equals method?

Answer (score 0):

Keep both a Set and a List. Use the Set to check for duplicates. Add to both Set and List if no dupe.

...assuming that Node has an .equals method defined...

```
private final Set<Node> seen = new HashMap<Node>();
private final List<Node> uniqueNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();


public void insertIfUnique(final Node n) {
  if (seen.contains(n)) {
    return;
  }
  seen.add(n);
  uniqueNodes.add(n);
}
```