# Concurrency - non blocking design in a foreach loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future

I am working on a service that returns a `List<Response>` object.

There are two kind of object that can build the response. One of them populates the content from internal data, the other reaches out to a service and gets the data.

```
for(Item item : items){
   if(item is external){
     call service and get result and populate Response and add to List
   }

   if(item is internal)
   {
     populate response object and add to list
   }
}
```

Current impl is procedural and blocking, what i want is a non blocking design such that, if the item is external fire the call and continue with next item in the list. Then when the loop is done, i can wait for all to finish.

What would be a good approach to do this? I m also considering creating seperate classes per responsibility.

**EDIT:** the reason to introduce is to reduce latency hits.

Comment: Another thing you may want to consider: what should happen when two threads try to access the same external item at the same time? It can result in two external calls unless you provide some kind of resource locking, resulting in unnecessary work when the second one could just wait for the first one to finish. +1, good question.

Comment: there is no synchronization. items are independent and client is thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) (thread pool with callbacks that remembers submitted tasks) seems like a goof git:

```
CompletionService<Response> executorService = 
    new ExecutorCompletionService<>(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
int totalExternal = 0;

for(Item item : items){
    if(item is external){
        executorService.submit(externalCall(item));
        ++totalExternal;
    }

    if(item is internal){
        populate response object and add to list
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < totalExternal; ++totalExternal) {
    addAsynchResultToResponseList(executorService.take().get());
}
```

Where `externalCall(item)` is defined as follows for clarity:

```
Callable<Response> externalCall(Item item) {
  return new Callable<Response>() {
    //...
  }
}
```

Obviously once you go asynchronous the result list can have an arbitrary order.

---

Another approach would be to use ordinary `ExecutorService` and have an intermediate `List<Future<Response>>`. The trick is to use [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/AsyncResult.html) wrapper to wrap internal responses (it creates `Future` that is immediately done and returns passed value).

```
List<Future<Response>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for(Item item : items){
    if(item is external){
        futures.add(executorService.submit(externalCall(item)));
    }

    if(item is internal){
        futures.add(new AsyncResult(synchResponse));
    }
}
```

Now you can simply iterate over `futures`. `AsyncResult` will return immediately as the value was already computer when it was created (`synchResponse`). But you will have to wait for `Future`s returned from a thread pool.

Remember that `Future.get()` allows you to retrieve original exception. Also the order of `Future`s in the list is the same as the order of original items, so if nth `Future` fails, nth item in `items` list was the cause.

Comment: `CompletionService` works well enough, so your solution is correct, but it's more appropriate to use `CompletionService` when you care about getting the results in the order they're completed (hence why it's called `CompletionService`). Maintaining a list of `Future` objects returned from the executor then iterating over them to get the results would suffice. Also, he won't have arbitrary order anymore, it'll be the order in which they were submitted.

Comment: I m not interested in the order as long as they return, however, if fails, i have to handle the exception or timeout. and need to know which one failed actually.

Comment: @Brian: well, you are right, +1. I chose `CompletionService` to avoid extra list and have everything encapsulated. On the other hand extra `totalExternal` variable is required. I am not sure if `while(executionService.poll() != null)` instead is safe here (?)

Comment: If you want the order, just pass the index of the task to the callable and return it along with the original return value.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz IIRC, it wouldn't be safe, since `poll` returns `null` if nothing is ready, even if there are still tasks being executed.

Comment: @biziclop That would require creating an entire new class for the returned value, though. That'd get pretty messy.

Comment: @DarthVader If you have the `Future` (which you do for both approaches) you'll get that information. `Future.get` throws an `ExecutionException` when the task fails via exception. You can get the original exception using `getCause` to figure out how it failed.

Comment: @DarthVader: have a look at my update, I suggest another solution based on your requirements above.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I will look into it.

Comment: @Brian Why would it be messy? A simple class with two final fields is hardly the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is wrap all the operations in `Callable`s, submit them to an `ExecutorService`, store the returned `Future`s in a list.

Then when they all finished, populate the list of results in the main thread.

Comment: All the operations doesnt require to be in Callable only the external entities does.If the entity is internal, I have the data in memory, i dont need to add thread overhead to it.

Comment: @DarthVader I doubt it would affect performance in a noticeable way. My principle is to always try the simple solution first, optimise later.

Comment: I agree with what @biziclop said. It is, after all, [what the experts do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015244/example-to-write-optimised-code-by-seeing-compiler-code-of-built-in-classes/13015420#13015420) (answer is more relevant than question). Optimize your code if it causes problems, write the cleaner solution first so it'll make sense if you or someone else looks at it again months or years from now.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things going when the item is external, the operation `call service` should initiate an asynchronous activity of some sort (e.g., a `Thread` or `Runnable` submitted to some sort of `Executor`). This activity should have a call-back mechanism so that after `get result` is complete, it can carry out the last part of the task: `populate Response and add to List`.

You'll have to synchronize access to `List` or arrange for all access to be single-threaded.